# 1062 Soap Fault Exception. Shipping address not set?

Tags: exception, soap, fault

- request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                          "shoppingCartShippingMethod");
                  request.addProperty("sessionId", SessionId);
              request.addProperty("quoteId",CartId);
              request.addProperty("shippingMethod","flatrate_flatrate");

  ```
          Log.e("shippingrespomnse...", request.toString());

              env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

              SoapObject methodset;
              methodset = (SoapObject) env.getResponse();


                  Log.e("shippingrespomnse...", methodset.toString());
  ```